# Logical OR operator in string comparison?

Tags: c#

Why does this comparison fails? How do I compare for alternating strings in csharp ?

```
Static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string varFoo = "cat";

        if (varFoo != "cat" || varFoo!="duck")
            Console.WriteLine("You can enter.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not allowed.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Just wanted something as

```
If(Either cat or a Duck)
    // You're not allowed
else
   // you are welcomed.
```

Comment: Look at the logical operator you used again and think. :) Every object is either not a cat *or* not a duck. This is true of cats, ducks and anything else you can think of.

Comment: it will allowed as it is a OR condition

Comment: second condition is true so it will go in

Comment: "cat" is not "duck" so the `if` statement returns true

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to stop cats **and** ducks instad? `if `varFoo != "cat" && varFoo!="duck"``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your comments, "cat" is allowed (and I suppose "duck" is also allowed).

```
if (varFoo == "cat" || varFoo=="duck")
```

With your last edit (cat and duck can't enter).

```
if (varFoo != "cat" && varFoo !="duck")
```

this means :
if `varFoo == "cat"` : assertion will fail (left part is evaluated, as it is false, right part isn't evaluated => false).

if `varFoo == "duck"` : assertion will fail (left part is evaluated, it's true, then right part is evaluated, it's false => false)

this is just boolean way of life :

```
true or false => true
true or true => true
true and false => false
false and true => false
```

Comment: +1 - I believe this is what the OP requires. (From the comment by OP `The cat is allowed`)

Comment: @Raphael: But he commented that it fails because the cat _is_ allowed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, I must admit it's not that clear. As I understood, "You can enter" if varFoo == "cat" (cat is allowed). Well, I gave your "understanding" too.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: _"The cat is allowed ._."_ was the direct answer of the question _"in what way does it fail?"_ and `._.` is the smiley for being stressed out ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to check for either & not both that's why I used a Logical OR instead of AND. VarFoo can either be a cat or a duck, I could have used a switch but that is another thing...

Comment: I thought it would evaluate as if (either cat or duck) { // don't let 'em enter }, updated my post.

Comment: @DamienJoe then second "version" of answer is correct. I completed my answer.

Comment: Thanks Raphael for all the details. Tim is right about the && operator.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus can you tell me why (!=) returns false if we see it as an expression like if (Expression) { do this; } Similary, if (animal!="cat"){// Allow } should return true as the animal is cat? Why does it returns a false?

Comment: @DamienJoe let's say variable animal is "cat". And the test is : `if(animal!="cat")` . Which means : tell me if this assertion is true or false : "variable animal is different from cat". As variable animal is not different from cat, result is false. Is it more clear ?

Answer (score 3):

One of your conditions is always true, no matter what the actual value is. You probably wanted a different comparison.

Considering the updated question, you'd be looking for the expression `varFoo != "cat" && varFoo != "duck"`, as you obviously confused `&&` (both conditions have to be true) and `||` (either condition have to be true).

Answer (score 2):

From your comment

> Q: in what way does it fail? – dutzu
>
> A: The cat is allowed ._.

i assume that you want to keap away cats **and** ducks.

You condition fails because of the [Logical OR Operator `||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx). The second condition gets evaluated because `"cat" != "cat"` returns false but `"cat" != "duck"` returns true. That's why cats are also allowed to enter.

You probably want to stop both from entering with

```
if (varFoo != "cat" && varFoo != "duck")
    Console.WriteLine("You can enter.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not allowed.");
```

**Update** You last edit supports my opinion:

> Just wanted something as

```
If(Either cat or a Duck)
    // You're not allowed
```

Understand it differently: You define an action, this is to prevent some animals from entering. You want to apply this action on `cats` **and** `ducks`. You need an `AND` instead
 of an `OR`. (see above code)

Another approach which does the same is to define a collection of forbidden animals and use `Contains`:

```
IEnumerable<string> forbiddenAnimals = new List<string>(){ "cat", "duck" };
if(forbiddenAnimals.Contains(varFoo))
    // You're not allowed
else
    // you are welcomed
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your wonderful response. I wanted to keep Cats 'OR' Ducks away so I used a Logical OR. I thought the if condition would evaluate on either, if being a match. Updated my post.

Comment: @DamienJoe: It's still not clear, there`s is no reasonable "keep Cats **'OR'** Ducks away". If you want to keep both away you would use `AND` (in language, database or programming).

Comment: @DamienJoe: Edited my answer to make it(hopefully) more clear.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I really like the 2nd approach you advised, it is very clear & concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (varFoo != "cat" || varFoo!="duck")
```

translation:

varFoo is not equal to `cat` OR varFoo is not equal to `duck`. Since varFoo is not `duck`; it returns true.

Comment: Are both of the conditions being evaluated in the end ?

Comment: if first condition is true, then the second one will not be processed. But in this case, since first condition is false, second one is evaluated.

Comment: How do I check for either?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
if (varfoo != "cat" && varfoo != "duck")
  //You can enter.
```

With the || it will always fail, on all strings.

Answer (score 1):

`if(varFoo != "cat" || varFoo != "duck")`
so
`if( false || true )` false or true == true.
it doesn't fail.